# Get double reload with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting some troubles with angularjs.
Please take a look my video:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Le3jZp2jEew?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I just try add data-ng-controller in body, but it's still same.
Please help me.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Please take a look video in here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Le3jZp2jEew

Comment: Instead of video with some clicking sounds, can you show us your code and explain the problem?

Comment: Update code Buddy that helps for trouble shoot

Comment: You are obviously binding event handlers repeatedly. Provide relevant code that manages the submit

Comment: Thank you about your answer. I've solved it using off() in jquery.
So when click again it still add new function to cache